# Is there an easy way to run multiple trials of a loop at once through parallelization in R?

Tags: r

I have a code that is a series of nested for loops. The outer for loop iterates through 10 integers to produce a data frame. The integers are completely mutually exclusive, but the code is quite slow. I wanted to know if it were possible, through parallelization to run several loops at the same time. I was intrigued by foreach, but it doesn't seem like the combine functionality lends itself to producing data frames after a series of nested for loops. Am I along the right lines with foreach, or is there a better option?

Here is a culled down version of my code. The last line is the output from the loop.

```
foreach(tra=lowageband:highageband) %do% {      
  ptptdata <- fresh.data
  cols <- c('FinalSalary', 'FinalDCBalance', 'FinalSSLow', 'FinalSSHigh')
  trials <- 1:numtrials
  ##[LOTS OF VECTORIZATION REDACTED]## 
  #START LIFE CYCLE LOOP# <- This exact code is repeated a few times   
  for(trial in 1:numtrials){
      [CODE REDACTED]
    for(row in 1:countlc) {

      [CODE REDACTED]
      for (i in 1:dur){

      [CODE REDACTED]

      }

      [CODE REDACTED]

    }

      [CODE REDACTED]

    new_cols <- c(outer(cols, trial, paste, sep = '_'))
    ptptdatalc[new_cols] <- ptptdatalc[cols]
      }
        
  final.model.data <- rbind(ptptdatalc,ptptdata_overretage)       
  assign(paste0("ModelDataAt",tra),final.model.data) 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried not `assign`ing the result? Try commenting out that line and instead finish with `final.model.data` to return this value.

Comment: It returns 10 tibbles in the console but no data frames are saved. Also, that last assign lets me name the data frame outputs, and I'm not sure how I would do that otherwise. It's basically producing ten of the same data files (except the tra variable changes the calculation a bit).

Comment: You must assign the return value of the outer loop, `ModelDataAt_list <- foreach(...)`. As for the names, afterwards one instruction is enough: `names(ModelDataAt_list) <- paste0("ModelDataAt",lowageband:highageband)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`doParallel` package which use `foreach` as base can do that. And it is really depend on how you structure your data and output it so that you can combine it back to dataframe.

```
library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel(detectCores())

trial_results <- foreach(tra=lowageband:highageband) %dopar% {      
  ptptdata <- fresh.data
  cols <- c('FinalSalary', 'FinalDCBalance', 'FinalSSLow', 'FinalSSHigh')
  trials <- 1:numtrials
  ##[LOTS OF VECTORIZATION REDACTED]## 
  #START LIFE CYCLE LOOP# <- This exact code is repeated a few times   
  for(trial in 1:numtrials){
      [CODE REDACTED]
    for(row in 1:countlc) {

      [CODE REDACTED]
      for (i in 1:dur){

      [CODE REDACTED]

      }

      [CODE REDACTED]

    }

      [CODE REDACTED]

    new_cols <- c(outer(cols, trial, paste, sep = '_'))
    ptptdatalc[new_cols] <- ptptdatalc[cols]
  }
        
  final.model.data <- rbind(ptptdatalc,ptptdata_overretage)       
  list(name = paste0("ModelDataAt_",tra), model_data = final.model.data)
}
```

Once you done you can combind them depend on how you want to with `pluck` function from `purrr` combind with `bind_rows`

```
library(purrr)
combined_data <- bind_rows(map(trial_results, .f = pluck, "model_data"))
```

In case you want to filter the results you can use `keep` :

```
filtered_list <- keep(trial_results,
                      .p = function(x) { x$name == "ModelDataAt_ABC" })
# Then combind just like previously
filtered_combine_data <- bind_rows(map(filtered_list, .f = pluck, "model_data"))
```